# only whitespace content allowed before start tag and not P (position: START_DOCUMENT seen P... @1:1) @ line 1, column 1

Tags: eclipse, git, jenkins

```
POM file :: I am using 4 java classes in this project. Build getting sucuess but 
POM FILE::
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
                       http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Login</groupId>
  <artifactId>Login</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>LoginMavan</name>
</project>
```

Getting below error message:

> [INFO] Scanning for projects... [ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were
>   encountered while processing the POMs: [FATAL] Non-parseable POM
>   C:\Users\KANE1354\workspace\Login\target\Login-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:
>   only whitespace content allowed before start tag and not P (position:
>   START_DOCUMENT seen P... @1:1)  @ line 1, column 1  @  [ERROR] The
>   build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1] [ERROR]    [ERROR]   The
>   project 
>   (C:\Users\KANE1354\workspace\Login\target\Login-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar)
>   has 1 error [ERROR]     Non-parseable POM
>   C:\Users\KANE1354\workspace\Login\target\Login-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:
>   only whitespace content allowed before start tag and not P (position:
>   START_DOCUMENT seen P... @1:1)  @ line 1, column 1 -> [Help 2]

Please help me to solve this issues.

Answer (score 2):

Try deleting the "repository" folder in maven's .m2 folder. The maven local repository is a local folder that is used to store all your project's dependencies. The location of your local repository can be changed in your user configuration. The default value is ${user.home}/.m2/repository/.

Comment: This worked for me. To clarify: Delete your projects and the contents on disk from Eclipse. Close Eclipse. Delete ~/.m2/repository. Reopen eclipse. Reimport your project(s) from github.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem. In my case the POM downloaded in to my `.m2/repository` were corrupted and did not have a valid XML syntax. I did a `clean install -X` so that I could see the detailed error log and identify which POMs were corrupted

I deleted all the error causing POMs from `.m2/repository` and did a `clean install` and it worked!